# Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?

Tags: string, yaml

Say I have the following string:

```
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

And I think its too long for one line in my YAML file, is there some way to split that over several lines?

```
>-
    abcdefghi
    jklmnopqr
    stuvwxyz
```

Would result in `"abcdefghi jklmnopqr stuvwxyz"` which is close, but it shouldn't have any spaces.

Answer (score 64):

Use double-quotes, and escape the newline:

```
"abcdefghi\
jklmnopqr\
stuvwxyz"
```

Comment: Single quotes also appear to work, and all indentation (even unequal indentation) appears to be stripped. Thanks!

Comment: i am using this for YAML in puppet "Hiera" and single quotes does not work, as they do not honor \ as an escape character in RUBY YAML at least. have not tested it with other YAML parsers.

Comment: See [this other StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210) for a good overview of all the different wrapping styles in YAML.

Comment: Single-quotes shouldn't behave like that. From the spec: `it is only possible to break a long single-quoted line where a space character is surrounded by non-spaces.`

Comment: for certain python API operation, using single quotes adds a space in the breakpoint of string, but double quotes works fine... thanks :)

Answer (score 32):

There are some subtleties that Jesse's answer will miss.

YAML (like many programming languages) treats single and double quotes differently.  Consider this document:

```
regexp: "\d{4}"
```

This will fail to parse with an error such as:

> found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 1 column 9

Compare that to:

```
regexp: '\d{4}'
```

Which will parse correctly.  In order to use backslash character inside double-quoted strings you would need to escape them, as in:

```
regexp: "\\d{4}"
```

I'd also like to highlight Steve's comment about single-quoted strings.  Consider this document:

```
s1: "this\
  is\
  a\
  test"

s2: 'this\
  is\
  a\
  test'
```

When parsed, you will find that it is equivalent to:

```
s1: thisisatest
s2: "this\\ is\\ a\\ test"
```

This is a direct result of the fact that YAML treats single-quoted strings as literals, while double-quoted strings are subject to escape character expansion.

Comment: Excellent summary. Thank you.

I just hit an issue where:
```
s1: "url?test=foo&\
     more&\
     params"
```
parsed, but set evetrything after it to be part of the string, but:
```
s1: "url?test=foo\
     &more\
     &params"
```
worked fine. Any idea why?

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you've described. You may want to open a new question where you include both the YAML data and the code necessary to reproduce the problem.