# YAML multiline wrap without space

Tags: yaml, word-wrap

I tried to understand the specifications here but they're actually quite difficult to understand.

http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2779048

As far as I can see, there are three ways of wrapping text but their function is very similar... in fact so similar that I don't get the point in having all of them instead of one or two.

Well my problem is that I have some String that is really long (~700 characters) but has no whitespaces.
Now of course I want to put it into multiple lines but there seems to be no way to do so without having any linefeeds or space characters that I do not want.

So is this actually possible?

```
---
aTest:
    hereComes
    SomeText
    ThatShould
    NotHave
    AnyWhitespaces
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268391/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-long-string-that-doesnt-have-any-whitespace-on-mul)

Comment: +1 for "_the specifications_ [...] _they're actually quite difficult to understand._" still holding true almost 10 years later. Every time I look at it I feel like diving deep down into a doctoral thesis that broke out of the university ivory tower accidentally with a bloodcurdling howl in a moonless, dark night. If RFCs were written like that we'd still use fax only.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

It's possible. See. [Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268391/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-long-string-that-doesnt-have-any-whitespace-on-mul)

Double-quoted example:

```
"abcdefghi\
jklmnopqr\
stuvwxyz"
```

Single quotes may also work depending on the parsing library so YMMV.

Comment: See [this other StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines/21699210#21699210) for a good overview of all the different wrapping styles in YAML.

Comment: Single quotes do not work - you get a literal backslash and newline

Comment: Single quotes worked on a YAML parsing library I was using at the time, may have been a bug in the library perhaps. Sorry about that guys

Comment: I tested with an online tool and worked differently than kustomize (the tool I'm using). Always test with your actual services!

Answer (score 0):

If your yaml is ansible, you can use jinja2 to join the pieces together.

```
long_list:
    - foo
    - bar
    - baz

long_string: "{{ long_list | join('') }}"
```

Yields "foobarbaz"