# Spring - Read YAML with multiline property value over @Value

Tags: spring, yaml

Currently I'm implement a YAML File over @PropertySouce and read the Property itself over @Value.
But now I have a multiline Property in my YAML File and want to read it the same way. (I want to store my sql Queries outside of my code)

I know, that I can indicate a multiline YAML String over ">" or ">-" or "|".
But when I try this and read the Property over @Value, I'm only getting the ">" as result in my String.
So, is there a way to read the multiline YAML Property completly?

I know, that I can escape each line with a backslash, but this is not the best solution for me.

So for e.g. I want to read the key "multilinekey" in my test.yml:

```
multilinekey: >
   Hi, I am a multiline String.
   But I can't get readed over @Value by spring.
```

And want to implement this value in my Code as follow:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:/test.yml")
public class myTestClass
   @Value("${multilinekey}")
   private String multiline;

   ...
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Or is there a better way to outsource my sql Queries in own files and include them easyly over @Value?

Comment: So you're saying, using the code you show, there's a `>` in the variable *multiline*? That means that the file is not parsed as YAML – did you configure Spring to do that? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28829727/347964).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to flyx
the yml File was not parsed as yaml File.
So [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28303758/how-to-use-yamlpropertiesfactorybean-to-load-yaml-files-using-spring-framework-4/28829727#28829727) is the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

controller.java

```
@Value("${str}")
String str;

@GetMapping("/probe")
public String probe(){
    return str;
}
```

application.yaml

```
str:"This is a very long sentence
    that spans several lines in the YAML
    but which will be rendered as a string
    with NO carriage returns."
```

Comment: When I try this in my code, I'm only get "This is a very long sentence" in the str Variable

Comment: can you paste your exact yml file and the class where you're referencing it using @Value? Seems strange that its not working for you

Comment: This does not work

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27282802/6409815), the correct way of doing this is using quotes and `\`:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql:\
    //localhost:5432/my-database"
```