# YAML Folding without spaces

Tags: yaml, line-breaks, readability

How can I break a long string in YAML (like long url, or filename/path), without newlines becoming spaces?

Example input:

```
url: >
  https://example.com/?what=Lorem
  %20ipsum%20dolor
  %20sit%20amet
```

Output:

```
{
  "url": "https://example.com/?what=Lorem %20ipsum%20dolor %20sit%20amet"
}
```

Desired output:

```
{
  "url": "https://example.com/?what=Lorem%20ipsum%20dolor%20sit%20amet"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268391/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-long-string-that-doesnt-have-any-whitespace-on-mul)

Answer (score 5):

Turns out Google failed on me and this question was already asked and answered on this site: [Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268391/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-long-string-that-doesnt-have-any-whitespace-on-mul)