# yaml multi line syntax without newline to space conversion

Tags: ansible

I have something like this dictionary:

```
env: qat
target_host: >
         {%if env in ['prd'] %}one
         {%elif env in ['qat','stg'] %}two
         {%else%}three
         {%endif%}
```

when I print it I get:

> ok: [localhost] => {
>       "var": {
>           "target_host": "two "
>       } }

So it is converting the \n at the end of the line to a space.  Which is exactly what it is supposed to do.  However in this case I am just trying to spread out the lines to make the structure of the if/else more readable and I don't want the extra space.  It works as expected if I put it all on one line without the > but I would like to be able to make it multiline just so its easier to read.

I found this question 
[Is there a way to represent a long string that doesnt have any whitespace on multiple lines in a YAML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268391/is-there-a-way-to-represent-a-long-string-that-doesnt-have-any-whitespace-on-mul)

So I could do:

```
env: qat
target_host: "{%if env in ['prd'] %}one\
              {%elif env in ['qat','stg'] %}two\
              {%else%}three\
              {%endif%}"
```

And that gives the desired result.

Is there anyway to accomplish this without cluttering it up even more?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In YAML, how do I break a string over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/in-yaml-how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Jinja* you can strip whitespaces/newlines by adding a minus sign to the start/end of a block. This should do the trick:

```
env: qat
target_host: >
         {%if env in ['prd'] -%}one
         {%- elif env in ['qat','stg'] -%}two
         {%- else -%}three
         {%- endif%}
```

* [Jinja 2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/) is the templating engine used by Ansible.

Comment: Perfect!  exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe what you need is the `|` literal?

```
env: qat
target_host: |
         {%if env in ['prd'] %}one
         {%elif env in ['qat','stg'] %}two
         {%else%}three
         {%endif%}
```

This will not 'fold' newlines into spaces, as oposed to `>`

Comment: this one adds "\n" for me

Comment: Add `-`, so `|-` This does not end a `\n` at the end