# Confluent Docker log4j logger level configurations

Tags: docker, logging, apache-kafka, log4j

I am running locally Kafka using the `confluentinc/cp-kafka` Docker image and I am setting the following logging container environment variables:

```
KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: ERROR
KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: >-
    org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,
    org.apache.kafka=ERROR,
    kafka=ERROR,
    kafka.cluster=ERROR,
    kafka.controller=ERROR,
    kafka.coordinator=ERROR,
    kafka.log=ERROR,
    kafka.server=ERROR,
    kafka.zookeeper=ERROR,
    state.change.logger=ERROR
```

and I see in the Kafka logs that Kafka is starting with the following configuration:

```
===> ENV Variables ...
ALLOW_UNSIGNED=false
COMPONENT=kafka
CONFLUENT_DEB_VERSION=1
CONFLUENT_PLATFORM_LABEL=
CONFLUENT_VERSION=5.4.1
...
KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR, org.apache.kafka=ERROR, kafka=ERROR, kafka.cluster=ERROR, kafka.controller=ERROR, kafka.coordinator=ERROR, kafka.log=ERROR, kafka.server=ERROR, kafka.zookeeper=ERROR, state.change.logger=ERROR
KAFKA_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL=ERROR
...
```

Still I see further down in the logs the `INFO` and `TRACE` log levels. For example:

```
[2020-03-26 16:22:12,838] INFO [Controller id=1001] Ready to serve as the new controller with epoch 1 (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-03-26 16:22:12,848] INFO [Controller id=1001] Partitions undergoing preferred replica election:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-03-26 16:22:12,849] INFO [Controller id=1001] Partitions that completed preferred replica election:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
[2020-03-26 16:22:12,855] INFO [Controller id=1001] Skipping preferred replica election for partitions due to topic deletion:  (kafka.controller.KafkaController)
```

How can I really deactivate the logs below a certain level? In the example above, I really want only `ERROR` logs.

- The approach above is the way described in the [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/operations/logging.html).
- And the Apache Kafka [source code](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/57903be49665566260160a6f1f995409ec48c9bc/config/log4j.properties) lists all sorts of loggers that I could not influence using the `KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS` Docker environment variable.

Comment: Do you see `INFO` level logs just for the controller?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous There were more than just the controller. I found the issue in the meanwhile. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I went and troubleshot the `Dockerfile`'s and inspected the Kafka container. The cause of this behaviour was the YAML multiline string folding.

Hence the provided environment variable (using a YAML multiline value) is at runtime:

```
KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR, org.apache.kafka=ERROR, kafka=ERROR, kafka.cluster=ERROR, kafka.controller=ERROR, kafka.coordinator=ERROR, kafka.log=ERROR, kafka.server=ERROR, kafka.zookeeper=ERROR, state.change.logger=ERROR
```

instead of (no spaces in between):

```
KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS=org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.apache.kafka=ERROR, kafka=ERROR, kafka.cluster=ERROR,kafka.controller=ERROR, kafka.coordinator=ERROR,kafka.log=ERROR,kafka.server=ERROR,kafka.zookeeper=ERROR,state.change.logger=ERROR
```

And this was visible inside the container in the generated `/etc/kafka/log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %p %m (%c)%n


log4j.logger.kafka.authorizer.logger=WARN
log4j.logger.kafka.cluster=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=DEBUG
log4j.logger.kafka.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.kafka=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka.coordinator=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka.log.LogCleaner=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka.controller=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka=INFO
log4j.logger.kafka.log=ERROR
log4j.logger.state.change.logger=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka.server=ERROR
log4j.logger.kafka.controller=TRACE
log4j.logger.kafka.network.RequestChannel$=WARN
log4j.logger.kafka.request.logger=WARN
log4j.logger.state.change.logger=TRACE
```

If you really need to split the long line in a YAML multiline value, you would have to use [this YAML syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6560524/454103).

More hints from the code:

- [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/5971a94e4e93e99723dcfa3cad77f4e35389bf77/debian/kafka/include/etc/confluent/docker/configure#L122) is where the `log4j.properties` file is generated when a confluent container is run.
- [these](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/v5.4.0-beta191017193411/debian/kafka/include/etc/confluent/docker/log4j.properties.template#L9-L16) are the default log levels that Kafka will start with.
- [these](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/57903be49665566260160a6f1f995409ec48c9bc/tests/kafkatest/services/kafka/templates/log4j.properties#L109-L134) should be all the loggers supported by Kafka

Comment: Note: Spaces matter. `log4j.logger. kafka.log=ERROR` might not get loaded

Comment: please note that in your one line example with no spaces, you do in fact still have spaces there. 

It should be:
KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.apache.kafka=ERROR,kafka=ERROR,kafka.cluster=ERROR,kafka.controller=ERROR,kafka.coordinator=ERROR,kafka.log=ERROR,kafka.server=ERROR,kafka.zookeeper=ERROR,state.change.logger=ERROR